# QR Codes & URL Shorteners - The Easiest Way?

Tags: php, forms, qr-code

I'm looking for a way to create a QR Code and a shortened link when a form is submitted. I have the QR Code bit, but the link is too long for me and the QR Code looks scary and complicated. The way it works is; the user types in (in this instance) a contract number. Then, a folder is created on the server of that contract number. (www.mysite.com/QR/$contractnumber). Then, using PHP again, I create a QR Code through Google because I know that every QR code will be linking to the same place, just a different ending of the link. The only bit that changes is the $POST...

I was wondering if there was a way to shorten the link before it goes to Google? It would have to be through php. The user enters the contact number in the form, then that number(usually around 5/6 digits) will be entered into a already existing command? I'm not an expert in anything, I just know some really random snippets of code... And HTML and CSS, of course.

Any help would be appreciated and judging by the few days I have been searching this, I think it might help a few people in the future. I would also like to confirm that the solution can't be one of this visual URLShorteners. If it is, it just needs to be the back-end of it, built into a existing form and QR Generator. Simple?

Comment: What's so scary about your current URLs? 5-6 digits is not much and a URL shortener will just create a random string of characters as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be able to use the TagLabs solution.  Check out the developer site; developer.taglabsinc.com and create a free account at portal.taglabsinc.com.  The platform will create the QR Code and shortened url.  You can manually create the QR Codes or leverage the API.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar challenge with one of our internal apps, and since any shortcut system (that I know of) relies on a database to translate what the short url *really* means , we opted to start our work from something that had already been done, rather than re-invent the wheel and based our solution on [yourls.org](http://yourls.org/).

We installed that, and populated the database from within our PHP, not really using the provided interface for anything except testing and it's statistics.  It's reasonably flexible, and while it does need some standards improvement, the core code that we were interested in (as you would be) was sound, and worked very well for us.

Comment: Interesting. I came across this and billions of other 'solutions' today and yesterday whilst looking for the answer, I didn't actually install this because it looked like it was for people that were looking to CREATE a URL Shortening service. I'll give that a go, it's the tweaking that I'm not looking forward to. How easy is/was it to implement to your current project(form)?

Comment: I had it running in less than 10 minutes - populating the db with our code was done by noon, and I spent the rest of the day playing with possibilities of how we might use the interface that is included.

Comment: and then I would just use the shortened link when calling the QR Code? For me it all just happens to fast, I have trouble knowing where to put what piece of code or .php file.

Comment: We used the interface to create a short url as we wanted it to appear and the real url that it would go to.  That gave us what we needed to understand in order to get our stuff into the database and to make it work properly.  From there, yourls did the work, and we just populated the db with our stuff....it was rally that simple.  Google isn't going to just magically know what the short url is, so you'll need to be sure to use them on any links, or have sitemap of them all, or some other method to make sure Google uses them.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, that's exactly what [a.zat.is](https://a.zat.is) for. Disclaimer: I made it.